# $H_\infty$ norm of a transfer function by Matlab

Tags: normed-spaces, matlab

Consider the simplest case:
   $$H(z) = \frac{z+1}{z+2}$$

I use two methods to find $H_\infty$-norm:

```
H = tf([1 1],[1 2],.001);

[ninf,fpeak] = norm(H,inf)
ninf =

0.6667
fpeak =

0
[ninf1,fpeak1] = hinfnorm(H)   
ninf1 =

Inf
```

It seems odd, the answers are different.
What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the system is unstable, the $H_\infty$ norm is infinite. You have a discrete time system with a pole greater than 1 in absolute value hence the answer `inf`. First one doesn't check for stability and converts it to state space system.

The discrepancy is due to the fact that `norm()` command only checks for $L_\infty$ not necessarily $H_\infty$ (for stable real-rational systems these coincide). That should be emphasized more in the documentation in my opinion.

For example, 2-norm is correctly caught.

```
>> [ninf,fpeak] = norm(H)
Warning: The H2 norm is infinite because the system is unstable. 
> In ctrlMsgUtils.warning (line 25)
  In ltipack.ssdata/normh2 (line 70)
  In ltipack.ltidata/normh2 (line 85)
  In ltipack.SystemArray/normh2_ (line 7)
  In DynamicSystem/norm (line 40) 

ninf =

   Inf


fpeak =

     []
```

This is even worse because now it reassures that the command is checking Hardy spaces. Matlab being matlab again.